# regex check and proceed next call

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

Iam new to gatling and scala.
I was trying to validate regex in galting-scala. 
My scenario. 
from the response capture (regex) X values, If available then execute step-ABC
If X value of component not found, ignore step_ABC

Comment: Explain what is the problem specifically with a small example.

Comment: I was trying to get some merchant information, if merchant having logoId, I will capture logoId , will call API to get image from backend , if logoId not found ignore the API call to get image. `regex(""""logoId":(.+?),""").exists.saveAs("logoId")`. i was trying to use `.doif(Session=> {
            (session("logoId") != null)
            session
          }` but above one shows error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example uses .exists, which asserts that the regex must be matched and returns a boolean, not the value of the match. So the "logoId" session variable will always get set, but won't have any data useful for making a subsequent request. Additionally, since the logo is optional in your case, you don't want the scenario failing if it isn't there.

Optional checks and the gatling EL support your use-case.

```
.exec(
   http("get merchant") 
   .get("some url")
   .check(
     regex(""""logoId":(.+?),""").optional.saveAs("logoId")
   )
   .doIf("${logoId.exists()}") {
     exec(...)
   }
```